# How to add data from wordpress tables to new database tables you have created

Tags: database, sql

I'm just learning this database stuff and so I am a bit confused and was hoping someone could push me in the right direction. I have managed to create users in the wp_tables I have created in my database.

[image]

Here are my specific questions.

1. What I am wondering is how do I link the hm_tables with data from the wp_tables. Wouldn't I need to insert a foreign key (i.e email address from wp_users) into the hm_tables. Because, otherwise I won't know which hm_account is linked to which wp_user? Is this dumb? And if so, HOW?
2. Also, I have become familiar with using WPDB commands, but when playing around with the hm_tables can I use $wpdb or do I need to use straight SQL commands.

Can you please give explicit instructions or examples as I get very lost at this early stage. I have read around but can't seem to find something that explains this at a level I can understand (which at this stage is quite low).

Comment: Are you using phpMyAdmin? And can I ask why are you using a different table prefix? (hm_ instead of wp_ that you apparently already have?) You do need to change your table prefix in your wp-config.php file.

Comment: I have actually managed to figure out the problem. Apparently wdpb does work with the hm_database files but I agree I should just change them. I guess my thinking was that if anyone looked at the plugin they would see what we had added.

Comment: 99 times out of 100, creating your own tables is unnecessary. I suggest looking into custom post types + meta data to store your plugin data. you get a whole bunch of functionality for free that you will otherwise have to code yourself when using your own tables.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to use double prefix like `wp_hm_account`, since it will allow you to recognize the tables (as you mentioned in comment) and you will be also able to use `wpdb` class properly.